# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions on window server

Tags: c#, sockets, model-view-controller

I am creating project on c# mvc on visual studio 2012 professional.
I am getting error "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" when i am creating raw socket in visual studio then 
I  run visual studio with administrator rights then this problem resolved. Then I publish code on window server 2012 same problem occur on it but I have administrator rights.

```
rawSocket = new Socket(sourceAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you should never run VS as Administrator. This will most likely mess up permission on a lot of files after a while.

Comment: @Torxed: Running VS as admin isn't really recommended, but it is a supported scenario, for things like debugging services.

Comment: ok sir. but when i publish code and place in inetpub->wwwroot on iis. i have also administrator rights on server. Can you suggest me how to set iis on administrator ?

Comment: @Jjaved: No, that's a really bad idea.  Put the raw sockets code in a service, and use a pipe or other IPC mechanism to use it from an IIS web app.

Comment: sir can you give me some link for reference